# accept4 blocks though SOCK_NONBLOCK is set

Tags: c, sockets, networking, nonblocking

I'm trying to accept a socket non-blockingly:

```
accept4(s, (struct sockaddr *) &peerAddress, &len,SOCK_NONBLOCK);
```

where as s is a fd, peerAddres is an address, and len, is its length.
I wish that accept won't block the thread.
Though, once I debug, the process is stuck at this line, while no connection is pending.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SOCK_NONBLOCK` just sets the newly accepted socket to non-blocking. It does not make `accept` itself non-blocking. For this one would need to set the listen socket non-blocking before calling accept.